# Overflow:hidden breaks z-index and translateZ but 'visible' does not. Why?

Tags: css, transform, z-index, masking, perspective

I'm trying to make a 3D art piece that has some layers in front of the frame layer and some layers behind the frame layer. I want the frame to mask off the layers behind it, and still be able to see the depth when I rotate the art.
I can do this without making the frame mask the layers behind it, and it works fine, but if I change the frame's overflow to hidden, or if I try a clipping path, the layers behind the frame lose their depth and become flat.

Here's a codepen example:
https://codepen.io/Tom-Columbus/pen/yLGVgRM

```
body {
margin: 0;
overflow: hidden;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
height: 100vh;
perspective: 1000px;
overflow: hidden; 
}

.artwork {
width: 509px;
height: 768px;
position: relative;
transform-style: preserve-3d;
transition: transform 0.5s;
box-shadow:
  rgba(22, 31, 39, 0.42) 0px 60px 123px -25px,
  rgba(19, 26, 32, 0.08) 0px 35px 75px -35px;
z-index: 12;
}

.layer {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-size: cover;
transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.frame {
position: fixed;
width: 509px;
height: 768px;
background-size: cover;
transform-style: preserve-3d;
border: 1px solid #333;
transform: translateZ(0px);
}
```

> I've tried masking the layers in the frame with these lines...
> overflow:hidden;
> clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);

^ In the example you can see the depth between the moon and the flower, but the edge of the moon and flower are also visible outside of the frame layer.

And if you apply "overflow:hidden" or the clipping path, the moon and flower's edge will no longer be visible outside of the frame layer, but they lose their depth and become flat.

I've read about relative and absolute positions messing with the masking, and I've tried a few different combos but can't seem to figure it out. I really appreciate any help I can get, feel like I'm out of ideas.

I'm on Mac (Ventura 13.5.1) and Chrome browser

Comment: Could you make your code into a runnable snippet with some actual images so we can see the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example also which browser and OS are you on?

Comment: I don't understand what the issue is. I copied your code (substituted the images) and there is no difference when `.frame` has `overflow: hidden` and/or `clip-path`. However, I realized that your example appears to have been truncated, which introduced HTML errors. It would be best if you could provide images of the desired result.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thanks for the eyes on this. I put together a codepen example that should help out.

In the example you can see the depth between the moon and the flower, but the edge of the moon and flower are also visible outside of the frame layer (on the right). 

And if you apply "overflow:hidden" or the clipping path, the moon and flower's edge will no longer be visible outside of the frame layer, but they lose their depth and become flat.

Comment: @ahaworth
I'm hoping the codepen example helps. Any more thoughts on this?

Comment: @TimR Hoping the updated code example makes things more clear. Any more ideas?

Comment: It seems the frame is being thought of in two ways. In one you want the frame to take part in the rotation. And in this case it is right that the items behind show (and the items in front have a gap between them and the frame on the right). In the other case you want the frame to be fixed and the items to move but clipped outside of it. Try putting a semi transparent background color on .frame to see this.